# OracleCommand timeout

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, oraclecommand

ODP.NET [documentation for OracleCommand.CommandTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFBGECA) says

> Default is 0 seconds, which enforces no time limit.
>
> When the specified timeout value expires before a command execution
> finishes, the command attempts to cancel. If cancellation is
> successful, an exception is thrown with the message of ORA-01013: user
> requested cancel of current operation. If the command executed in time
> without any errors, no exceptions are thrown.
>
> In a situation where multiple OracleCommand objects use the same
> connection, the timeout expiration on one of the OracleCommand objects
> may terminate any of the executions on the single connection. To make
> the timeout expiration of a OracleCommand cancel only its own command
> execution, simply use one OracleCommand for each connection if that
> OracleCommand sets the CommandTimeout property to a value greater than
> 0.

But a code like this works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OracleConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        string connString =
            "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myOracleHost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myServiceName)));User Id=system;Password=admin;Pooling = False;";
        string cmdString1 = "UPDATE employee SET empname = 'temp1' where id = 1";
        string cmdString2 = "Update employee set empname = 'temp2' where id = 2";
        conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
        var cmd1 = new OracleCommand(cmdString1, conn);
        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 30;
        var cmd2 = new OracleCommand(cmdString2, conn);
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 30;
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            //Locked the row with ID 1 with an uncommitted update operation outside this code
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Exception ORA-01013 Thrown as expected
        }
        try
        {
            //As per the documentation, this should not also work since this command object also uses the same connection as above and it timed out in the query above
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //But this still works fine. 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //no exception
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I am using the same `OracleConnection` object for both the command objects - `cmd1` and `cmd2`, and `cmd1` already timed out(as expected).
But, per the documentation, `cmd2` also should not run. But it still runs without any exception and updates the other row properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have multiple commands running on the connection, you have two commands running sequentially, one after the other. When the first command times out, there is no other command pending on the connection. Your code does not submit the second command for execution until after the first command has either succeeded or has thrown an exception.

The last paragraph from the documentation you quoted should read: *In a situation where multiple OracleCommand objects use the same connection **simultaneously**, ...*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Pooling=False;...")) // why?
    using (var cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand())
    using (var cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE employee SET empname = 'temp1' WHERE id = 1";
        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE employee SET empname = 'temp2' WHERE id = 2";
        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 30;
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 30;

        conn.Open();

        // there are no commands on conn yet

        try { cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); } // cmd1 is the only command on conn
        catch (OracleException) { } // if timeout, no other command affected

        // cmd1 is no longer on conn

        try { cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); } // cmd2 is the only command on conn
        catch (OracleException) { } // if timeout, no other command affected

        // cmd2 is no longer on conn
    }
}
```

Comment: Pooling is false since it is a nightly job (the server is for a single geography and is expected to be at near-zero loads at nights) and therefore setting Pooling off seems to be a better option when compared to the overhead involved in validating the connections returned from the pool.